# How to fix MissingPluginException on Agora video call?

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I'm building an App which can make Video calls, I'm using Agora SDK for the feature. I'm having a problem when I want to run the app on my device. Naturally it would ask for Camera and Microphone permission but it doesn't ask me and the video call feature won't start. Here's some of my code:

**The Function that gives me the error**

```
  Future<void> onJoin() async {
    // update input validation
    setState(() {
      _channelController.text.isEmpty
          ? _validateError = true
          : _validateError = false;
    });
    if (_channelController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      // await for camera and mic permissions before pushing video page
      await _handleCameraAndMic(); // doesn't asks for any permissions so the video call won't start
      //await _permissions();
      // push video page with given channel name
      await Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => CallPage(
            channelName: _channelController.text,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> _handleCameraAndMic() async {
    await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions(
      [PermissionGroup.camera, PermissionGroup.microphone],
    );
  }
```

**The Exception I'm getting**

> Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found
>   for method requestPermissions on channel
>   flutter.baseflow.com/permissions/methods)

I'm using [this as a reference](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Flutter-Quickstart) for bulding the feature

I'm not sure where did I do wrong because I'm very new to flutter development. Any help would be appreciated and if you need more code I will provide it to you, just feel free to ask. Thank you.

Comment: Hot reload/ Hot restart would not work if the plugin contain native code. You need to rebuild the project again to load new plugins, and then it will work.

Comment: @Darish I've already built it again but still doesn't work, is there any other suggestions?

Comment: how you added the plugin into your project?

Comment: did you add the permission handler dependency into your pubspec.yaml?

Comment: @Darish i did with the same version as the example i followed

Comment: means, you added permission_handler: '^4.2.0+hotfix.3' to your pubspec.yaml and rebuilt the project?? (not hot restart/reload).

Comment: @Darish yes that's correct

Comment: could you please create a sample repo to reproduce your issue and share it on github so that we can review it. Otherwise it is tough to guess the issue.

Comment: @Darish here you go https://github.com/cleanrun/klikproject

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue on their repo, see [this](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/141).

Probably the plugin is buggy, so you may try some other plugin.

Comment: thank you for your response, is there any more plugin that i could use that you may know? i've used simple permissions but it does the same